# Is $\int\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}\,\textrm{d}z=\int\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}x}\,\textrm{d}y$?

Tags: calculus

$$\int\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}\,\textrm{d}z=\int\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}x}\,\textrm{d}y$$

Is the above statement true? (I think it is because I often see some such manipulation.)

What does it even mean (precisely)?

If it's true, how do we prove it?

One way I've tried to read it is:

> The antiderivatives of $\frac{\textrm dy} {\textrm dx}$ with respect to $z$ are the same as the antiderivatives of $\frac{\textrm dz} {\textrm dx}$ with respect to $y$.

But I can't quite make sense of this last sentence, especially the "with respect to" bits.

Comment: As written it doesn't really make sense. Well, roughly speaking, $\int \frac{dy}{dx}dz=\frac{dy}{dx}\int dz$

Answer (score 3):

If $y$ and $z$ are functions of $x$ the both sides are equal to $\int \frac {dy} {dx} \frac {dz} {dx} dx$.